# Gradle not resolving mavenLocal() dependency

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-publish

I have a problem with resolving local dependency. I have a lib that I want to provide across my projects. So I've published it locally. The build.gradle looks like this:

```
...
plugins {
    ...
    id("maven-publish")
    ...
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            groupId = "com.wintermute.chatserver.core"
            artifactId = "core"
            version = "1.0"

            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
}
```

In the other project, which is requiring the dependency I've added in the build.gradle this:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

But when I try to resolve the dependencies gradle complains about not resolvable dependency:

```
Could not resolve com.wintermute.chatserver.core:core:1.0.
Required by:
    project :
```

It was successfull one time, then I've deleted the cache and since this it does not work anymore. Why is that? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If the cache you reference is the .m2 cache - did you republish the component after you deleted it?

Comment: I completely deleted the .m2 cache and executed the publishing task after clearing that cache.